# Function bounds in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot multiple bounded functions in gnuplot. I.e. plot x from 0 to 2 and x^2 from 1 to 3 and have them show up together.

How do you plot functions with different bounds?

I know how to do a piecewise function, like (x < 1 ? x : x**2). This is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
plot 0 <= x && x <= 2 ? x : 1/0, \
     1 <= x && x <= 3 ? x**2 : 1/0
```

We need to define what to draw outside the desired range, so we just use an undefined function `f(x)=1/0` so that nothing is graphed in these ranges.

Comment: Oops, that was obvious. Thanks!